# Как преобразовать UNIX время в дату

Tags: php, unix

У меня в базе есть значение с UNIX временем, например: `1533414201`.

Как в мне это значение конвертировать в дату например: `10.07.2014` без времени?

Answer (score 8):

```
$ts = 1533414201;

// Можно через setTimestamp
$d = new DateTime();
$d->setTimestamp($ts);

// или createFromFormat с форматом U
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $ts);

echo $d->format('d.m.Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на SQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1533414201), '%d.%m.%Y');

+----------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1533414201), '%d.%m.%Y') |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 04.08.2018                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$unix_timestamp = time();
echo date("d-m-Y",$current_timestamp);
```

Как форматировать вывод не должно составить труда.

Answer (score 0):

$timestamp = 1533414201;

$date = date('Y.m.d', $timestamp);

Подробнее читай http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php